# Using one socket object to send and receive multiple sockets in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, synchronization

In C#, I have a server application with multiple clients connecting.  I will only keep track of the IP address and port when a new socket is instantiated upon accept.  My question is that using only one socket object can I accommodate sending and receiving?  Is it possible for synchronous and asynchronous sockets?  Examples will be helpful.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with UDP, it's not possible with TCP and since you mention `Accept()` I assume you're using TCP and therefore it's not possible...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the socket object that is returned by accept method to send and receive to particular client. you can not use a single socket for all clients. socket is the end point through which communication is done